# Is there support for geo uri in latex?

Tags: latex, uri

Is geo uri supported in latex? are there any packages that support geo uri?

Ideally, I want to be able to do this:

```
{\href{geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35}{Home}}
```

When user clicks on the link default map app opens. just like mailto:

Regards

Comment: LaTex questions belong on the [TeX/LaTeX Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanks I posted it there

Comment: It was finally posted [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579666).